# Наполнение объекта при помощи файла

Tags: php, javascript

День добрый!

В php можно наполнить массив используя след. конструкцию

```
$a = include('array.php');
Файл array.php содержит строку return array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

Можно ли реализовать подобную конструкцию в JS?

```
var obj = script.js;
```

Comment: @zsiteru, речь про браузерный JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильный подход. Но вот синхронное и асинхронное решения:

Файл `script.js`, содержание:

```
array(10,20,30,40);
```

И сама функция:

```
function include(file, callback) {
    var data;

    window.array = function() {
        if(callback == undefined) {
            data = arguments;
        }
        else {
            callback.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        }
    }

    if(callback == undefined) {
        var xhrObj = XMLHttpRequest();
        xhrObj.open('GET', file, false);
        xhrObj.send('');
    }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    if(callback == undefined) { 
        script.text = xhrObj.responseText;
        return data;
    }
    script.src  = file;
}

var data = include('script.js');
console.log(data);

include('script.js', function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function include(filename)
{
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = filename;

    document.body.appendChild(js);
}
```

Скрипт будет подключен в DOM и выполнен

Comment: Да речь про браузерный JS.

Файл инклюдится, но значение объекту не присваивается.
т.е. в script.js содержится что то типо {'myKey':'myValue'};
var obj = include(script.js);
obj.myKey // myValue

Comment: @zsiteru, тут есть два (три) способа, плохой и хороший (и кривоватый):  
Плохой: window.obj = `{'myKey':'myValue'}` в файле  
Хороший: у вас есть основное приложение, скажм, app, доступное по `window.app`. Тогда делается функция-приемщик данных, а в файле пишется `window.app.pushData({'myKey':'myValue'});`. По факту это аналог JSONP.  
Кривой, но с наиболее корректной логикой: запросить файл средствами какой-нибудь jQuery как json-документ. При этом форматирование должно будет соблюдаться беспрекословно, но вы пытаетесь именно запросить дополнительные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный разымный способ как мне кажется это ajax запрос к файлу, содержащему скрипт.
Допустим, в файл array.js пишем return [2,7,35,7784,'foo','bar']. И делаем так:

```
var myArray;
$.get('array.js', {}, function(data){
    myArray = (new Function(data))();
});
```

Естественно, это, если у Вы используете jQuery. Если не используете то тогда:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'script.js');
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(request.readyState == 4){
          if(request.status == 200){
               myArray = (new Function(request.responseText))();
          }
     }
};
request.send();
```

Comment: разумней аяксом подгружать JSON файл и дальше парсить как JSON, а не как скрипт. Но автор пока еще не в теме, немного невлился)

Comment: Согласен. Код подгружать из вне это всегда Фу. Но, я отталкивался от задачи.

Comment: @Vladimir Kudinov тс вроде не говорил, что подгружаемый файл находится на другом домене.

Comment: Под "из вне" я имею ввиду из другого файла, не обязательно на другом домене или даже в другой директории.

Comment: @Vladimir Kudinov ну не согласен с вами))